# "Could not get any response" in Postman when using .Include()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postman

I have a statement like this in my HttpGet method in an MVC controller:

```
IEnumerable<UserExtension> iue = await DataContext.UserExtensions;
```

If I change the command to:

```
IEnumerable<UserExtension> iue = DataContext.UserExtensions.Include(ue => ue.UserRoles)
```

No exception is thrown in code, but I get the following response in Postman:

```
Could not get any response

There was an error connecting to http://localhost:60891/table/UserExtension.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

Any ideas why this has happened?

Without the `.Include()` clause, everything works, and the `UserRoles` is returned as NULL as expected.

Comment: Step through it, are any exceptions being thrown? What's the value of `iue` after the assignment? When/how are you realising the queryable?

Comment: As stated above "No exception is thrown in code". The iue looks to be populated OK. If I call the URL from Chrome, I get a good response, so deffo a Postman issue....

Comment: It can't be a postman issue if it works without the `.Include` and doesn't when it's added. What are you doing with `iue` to form the response? Please include enough code to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain there was no exception? This sounds like a try/catch block "swallowed" the exception.
You could try to debug the application to find out what is happening?

It may be possible that something in the data is not consistent with your model. E.g. a 1-1 relation in your code having 1-n items in the database.

Posting the code that retrieves the data may help us to find out what's going wrong.